# Graph in pgfplots: global style for all node labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I have this graph rendering three functions:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
    axis lines=center,
    xmin=-1, xmax=100,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1000,
  ]
  \addplot[
    domain=0:25,
    ] {x^2} node[label={\(x^2\)}] {};
  \addplot[
    domain=0:9.8,
    ] {2^x} node[label={\(2^n\)}] {};
  \addplot[
    domain=0:90,
    ] {x} node[label={\(n\)}] {};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to set the style of the node labels globally. Lets say that I want them with yellow background: I know I can do it locally, but if the style get complex the code becomes hard to read.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
    axis lines=center,
    xmin=-1, xmax=100,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1000,
    label style={font=\small}
  ]
  \addplot[
    domain=0:25,
    ] {x^2} node[label={[fill=yellow]:{\(x^2\)}}] {};
    \addplot[
      domain=0:9.8,
      ] {2^x} node[label={[fill=yellow]:{\(2^n\)}}] {};
    \addplot[
      domain=0:90,
      ] {x} node[label={[fill=yellow]:{\(n\)}}] {};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I add the styles for the node labels only once in the header?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Been a reader for a while, thanks!

Comment: Try `\tikzset{nodestyle/.style = {arguments here}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of Ti*k*Z's styling mechanims, which allow you to style all labels at once:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={fill=yellow}]
  \begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
    axis lines=center,
    xmin=-1, xmax=100,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1000,
    label style={font=\small}
  ]
  \addplot[
    domain=0:25,
    ] {x^2} node[label={\(x^2\)}] {};
    \addplot[
      domain=0:9.8,
      ] {2^x} node[label={\(2^n\)}] {};
    \addplot[
      domain=0:90,
      ] {x} node[label={\(n\)}] {};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, is actually easy :)